# Image not appearing in Firefox. Connection not secure

Tags: wordpress, image, ssl

We have a website we just launched here: https://soteloforjudge.com/

It seems to work in most browsers but when I go to it in Firefox the logo at the top and bottom of the page do not show up and I get a message that the connection isn't secure for some images.

The image we are using is: https://soteloforjudge.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Henry_Sotelo_for_Judge_2022_Reno_Nevada_bg.png

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just find the location in WP editor where you have added the background image and remove it then re add it and save. It should sort the issue. Here is your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it. I added a retina image for the logo in Wordpress and now it seems to be working. Maybe I had added that one previously and then deleted it. Not sure what happened but now it works.